# Desktop email client issue in Outlook

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, outlook, desktop

One of the user has sent an email
Which was not delivered to the recipient.
I can trace the email and found the "connection timed out " error in messages logs.
Is there any way that user can get to know that the email has not been delivered at the Desktop level.
The email is there in Sent item at sender end.

Comment: Outlook, on linux? are you sure ?

Comment: The email has been sent through the Outlook.while the I have traced the email on Linux server

Comment: you could tag the message so that the recipient is requested to acknowledge receipt. This is not bullet proof, the recipient could ignore the request. But you cannot setup the user to receive these types of error messages directly from the server without giving up security.

Comment: Which email server is hosting?

Comment: Please be more specific about the components involved. There is no Outlook for Linux. Are you referring to outlook.com as a mail provider? Are you referring to an on premise exchange installation? What is the actual name of mail client application on the desktop?

Comment: The user has sent an email from the Outlook on windows.The email server is linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the link which is related with the similar error `Connection Timed Out` will help you troubleshoot: [Why is my Linux email system failing to send email messages with a "Connection timed out (port 25)" message in the maillog file](https://www.linuxtopia.org/ProblemSolutions/smtp_port_25_timeout.html):

> This problem is almost always caused by the fact that the Internet
> Service Provider (ISP) to which you system gets in internet connection
> has decided to block port 25. ISPs often do this these days in an
> attempt to control the amount of spam that is being sent by some of
> their more unscupulous customers. In effect they are trying to
> contribute to reducing the level of spam on the internet but in doing
> so cause problems for the innocent.